# Toggle open by mouseover and close by moveout, not by a click

Tags: javascript, jquery, stack, toggle

jQuery "Toggle" function question.

Can toggle open initiated by mouseover and close by mouseout, but not by a click...

How to make it open and close by mouseover and mouseout ?

js as below :

```
$(function () { 
// Stack initialize
var openspeed = 300;
var closespeed = 100;
$('.stack>img').toggle(function(){
    var vertical = 0;
    var horizontal = 0;
    var $el=$(this);
    $el.next().children().each(function(){
        $(this).animate({top: '-' + vertical + 'px', left: horizontal + 'px'}, openspeed);
        vertical = vertical + 55;
        horizontal = (horizontal+.75)*2;
    });
    $el.next().animate({top: '-50px', left: '10px'}, openspeed).addClass('openStack')
       .find('li a>img').animate({width: '50px', marginLeft: '9px'}, openspeed);
    $el.animate({paddingTop: '0'});
}, function(){
    //reverse above
    var $el=$(this);
    $el.next().removeClass('openStack').children('li').animate({top: '55px', left: '-10px'}, closespeed);
    $el.next().find('li a>img').animate({width: '79px', marginLeft: '0'}, closespeed);
    $el.animate({paddingTop: '35px'});
});
// Stacks additional animation
$('.stack li a').hover(function(){
    $("img",this).animate({width: '56px'}, 100);
    $("span",this).animate({marginRight: '10px'});
},function(){
    $("img",this).animate({width: '50px'}, 100);
    $("span",this).animate({marginRight: '0'});
});
```

});

Comment: Then use [`hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) instead of `toggle()`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `.toggle`, use `.hover` function. ex,

```
$('.stack>img').hover(function() {
    //previos was togle
```